# Install homebrew using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to install Homebrew using a Makefile, the contents of the Makefile is this:

```
.PHONY: install
install:
    # Install homebrew
    /usr/bin/ruby -e $(shell curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

However this just prints the entire contents of the script, but it does not execute anything. I got as far as googling for this issue and seeing that the characters $, (, ) have a special meaning in a Makefile, however I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try just piping output from `curl` to `ruby` like this:

```
.PHONY: install
install:
    # Install homebrew
    curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install | ruby
```

Comment: So obvious actually, but thanks a lot! This indeed did work.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the following warning:

```sh
Warning: The Ruby Homebrew install is now deprecated and has been rewritten in Bash.
Please migrate to the following command:
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

You can modify @igagis answer as such

```
.PHONY:install
install:
    curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into needing sudo, then sudo telling me not to run as root so the command i used was:

```
sudo true
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh | sudo -u $$USER bash
```

Notes:

I use sudo true to run sudo and do nothing. that way the user can input their password. running sudo make from the terminal caused the $USER to be root. if you remove the sudo true line, then if sudo has not been run yet, the sudo access check will fail and not let you insert a password when running the curl line

the two $ makes the makefile write a literal $